# Issues with converting int to char in C

Tags: c, stm32, cortex-m

I've wrote a small function for debug purpose which sends string via USB to a terminal  :

```
void localprint(char* msg){
if(strlen(msg) > 60){
            usb_sendData(msg,60);
}
else usb_sendData(msg,strlen(msg));
```

}
the function works fine for strings like :

```
localprint(" I'm a test" ),
```

the message is displayed on terminal.
Now I want to get the  `adcValue`  which is an `int` on the terminal, for I've tried :

```
char t= (char)(((int)'0')+getADCValue(9)); // getting the ADC value of 0th channel 
localprint(&t);
```

this doens't work at all , I'Ve also tried :

```
char t= (char) getADCVAlue(9);
localprint(&t);
```

it doesn't work neither. So my question is any idea how can I do that . I'm using uC STM32f10xx and ARM gcc. 
thanks for any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything about the range of possible ints, something like this will work:

```
char buffer[32];
sprintf(buffer, "%d", getADCVAlue(9));
localprint(buffer);
```

Since you did `0+`, I'm assuming it's one digit, so you could go

```
char buffer[2];
buffer[0] = '0' + getADCVAlue(9);
buffer[1] = '\0';
localprint(buffer);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I've tried to used but I get only 0 I've change the size of the buffer, but it didn't help. sprintf gives me an error undefined reference to `_sbrk'

Comment: and by the way its 4 digits

Answer (score 0):

Answer from **John3136** will work fine if you replace `sprintf` with some lightweight implementation of this, e.g `xsprintf` from [elm-chan](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/strf/xprintf.html) which I found extremely helpful in embedded programming. Or you must have some stubs for system calls like `_sbrk` if you want to use `sprintf`.

I can't comment solution from **John3136** because I don't have enough reputation.